# How to prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (n+1)^{1/n} = 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

We know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n} = 1$. Using this, how can we prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (n+1)^{1/n} = 1$?

Recalling the proof of the former limit, I was able to modify it to prove the latter limit. But I was wondering if we could just use the limit we have already calculated to prove this limit which is related to it.

Comment: $1\le(n+1)^{1/n}\le (2n)^{1/n}=2^{1/n}n^{1/n}$. Now Squeeze...

Comment: @DavidMitra Please make your comment into an answer so that I can upvote and accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note $$1\le (n+1)^{1/n}\le (2n)^{1/n}=2^{1/n}n^{1/n}.$$ Now you could apply the Squeeze Theorem using your known limit.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (n+1)^{\frac1n}=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} (n+1)^{\frac1{n+1}}\right)^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}n}$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate how do you get that limit in the power?

Comment: @Maverick, for positive real value $a$, we have $a^b=(a^c)^{\frac bc}$ where $b,c$ are real numbers  http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws/Power_of_Power

Comment: That is ok, but why the limit?

Comment: @Maverick, you can use the formula you mentioned

Comment: I think what you intended to write was $\left(\lim (n+1)^{1/(n+1)}\right)^\frac{n+1}{n}$

Comment: @Maverick, just to re-confirm, the outer limit is $\frac{n+1}n=1+\frac1n$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10188/discussion-between-maverick-and-lab-bhattacharjee)