# Limit n approaches infinity of $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+n)^{\frac 1n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

I was wondering about $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+n)^{\frac 1n}$. It is may not be as famous as Euler's limit but worth discussing. I searched the net but didn't get relevant proofs. I might miss though.

I thought one way, using LHopital, yeah kind of using a big result and don't know whether the proof is correct or not. I believe that there are plenty of easier proofs but I am not getting one.

Thinking $\lim_{x \to \infty}\log((1+x)^{\frac 1x})=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{1+x}=0$ by raising it to the exponent we get the limit to be $1$.

Let me know your thoughts I think I still have to prove that the sequence is convergent first.

Comment: The limit is $1$ and you have proved it correctly.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/191175/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/470522/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2090985/42969

Comment: Yeah I approved that post.

Comment: I thought I asked a better representation of this question so that now people will be redirected to the desired answer quickly but still in google search it is not showing. I hope in mathstack search it will help. By the way, how do you quickly get that this question was asked before?